# File download on ajax call in mvc4 c#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making an ajax call to the controller. There i am creating a pdf file.

How can i sent it to the browser so that user can download it.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Createpdf(string htmlpage)
    {
        var htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
        string htmlCode = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><title>Report</title>/head><body>" 
            + htmlpage 
            + "</body></html>";
        string baseUrl = null;
        pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToMemory(htmlCode, baseUrl);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\HubReport.pdf", pdfBuffer);
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
        //   String.Format("{0}; filename=HubReport.pdf;size={1}", "attachment", pdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult).

Comment: Set `Response.ContentType` to `application/x-pdf`

Comment: As far as I know, you can't directly download a file using AJAX. Instead, you should point your browser (in your AJAX response event) to the URL of the download file.

Comment: yes exactly...how can i point it

Comment: My bad. I overlooked the post, sorry about that. You are anyways writing the file to the disk. So you can return the Url from the controller and then just open that in a new window.Or This Url can be a handler or a MVC action which gets the file for you when you pass on the file name to it.

Comment: i am new to mvc and c#...can you please give me code or some link

Answer (score 1):

I havent tested this but this might give you some pointers.

You pass your file name to this action. and give this action as the url of new window.

```
public FileResult Getfile(string downloadfileName)
{
    byte[] fl = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\" + downloadfileName);
    string fileName = "Somefile.pdf";
    return File(fl, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

**EDIT**

I tested this and it works absolutely fine

here is my Sample View Code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //You need to call this click function from you ajax Success callback.
        $("#getFile").click(function () {
            window.open('@Url.Action("GetFile","Home","test.pdf")', "downloadfile");
        });
    });

</script>
<input type="button" value="GetFile" id="getFile" />
```

Here is the Controller

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public FileResult Getfile(string downloadFileName)
    {
        byte[] fl = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\sampleFile.pdf");
        string fileName = "Somefile.pdf";
        return File(fl, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    }
}
```

And here is the output

[image: Sample output]

Comment: It didn't work because `window.open` initiating an HTTP **GET** request, while the OP Action (`Createpdf`) is marked with `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: I know the action is marked as **POST**. What I meant to say was after creating a file another `Action` would be called which downloads the file. The original `CreatePDF` action would send the created file name which will be passed on to the `Getfile` Action