# Links for pdf files in server from static mvc web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have few links to pdf files store in server in my static page. I would be able to click each link that would open a pdf file in browser. I referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873180/provide-static-file-download-at-server-in-web-application). But it is not working as I intended.

Here is my action method:

```
public ActionResult GetFileFromServer(string filename)
{
   string folderpath = StrGlobal.file_folder.ToString();
   string filepath = Path.Combine(folderpath, filename);
   filepath = Path.GetfullPath(filepath);

   return File(filepath, "application/pdf");
}
```

My view:

```
<p>
   @Html.ActionLink(
   linkText: "ABC Document",
   actionName:"GetFileFromServer",
   controllerName:"StaticPage",
   routeValues:new {filename = "ABC.pdf"},
   htmlAttributes:null
   )
</p>
```

If I replace and hardcore filename in this line:

```
string filepath = Path.Combine(folderpath, "ABC.pdf");
```

It will open that specific pdf file. Otherwise I get an error saying

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path2
```

Seems like value is not getting passed from view to controller. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Have u tried debugging the action method to see if the parameter is getting populated or not?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. And parameter is not getting populated.

Comment: i think you should try passing just "abc" as filename in `ActionLink()`. If the parameter gets populated, then you might have to change a bit of your action logic

Comment: What does the generated link look like on the page? Also have you edited any MapRoutes that might effect routing?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="/staticpath/ABC.pdf" download>
  Donloadpdf
</a>
```

Hi,

We can resolved issue by easy way with using html download functionality.