# Allowing the user downloading a file located in a specific IIS folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have the following issue: ASP-MVC
I want to put a file in a folder in IIS and allow users surfing my site to download it.

In my site, I will have a link that points to an action method in my controller, and within this method I want to put the needed code. Never dealt with this issue before, will appriciate a  code sample. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code , taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult), will accomplish what you want.

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c:\folder\myfile.ext");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get a specific file based on some passed-in ID, you can use the Controller.File function as described here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492492(v=vs.100).aspx

Here's an example controller function from that page:

```
public ActionResult ShowFileFN(string id) {
  string mp = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + id);
  return File(mp, "text/html");
}
```

This will return a binary stream of the named file with the specified MIME content type, in this case "text/html".  You'll need to know the MIME type for each file you're returning.

Here's a function to get the MIME type of a file based on its extension:

```
public static string GetMimeType(string fileName)
{
    string mimeType = "application/unknown";
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
    if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
        mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
    return mimeType;
}
```