# list down the files in a folder in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-io

I want to list all the files in folder once page loading . so

For that I just created like this

HTML code

```
<input id="idd" type="file" multiple="true" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
```

Script

```
@section scripts{   

 <script type="text/javascript">    

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/filesinfolder',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                    $('#idd').append('<li><a href="http://'+ val.Url +'" target="_new">' + val.Url + '</a></li>');
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.log('Response code:' + xhr.status);
                console.log('[Error:' + err + '] ' + status);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Controller method

```
    public JsonResult filesinfolder()
    {
        DirectoryInfo salesFTPDirectory = null;
        FileInfo[] files = null;

        string salesFTPPath = "C:/filePath";

        salesFTPDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(salesFTPPath);
        files = salesFTPDirectory.GetFiles();

        files = files.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToArray();

        var salesFiles = files.Where(f => f.Extension == ".xls" || f.Extension == ".xml" || f.Extension == ".jps" || f.Extension == ".jpg" || f.Extension == ".jpeg" || f.Extension == ".png");

        return Json(salesFiles.ToList());
    }
```

But this is isn't list down anything at all , but once I debug I can see this `filesinfolder` method calling and finding files in folder.

Comment: What do you get in javascript console ? any errors ?

Comment: You cant append `<li>` elements to an `<input>` Create a `<ul id="idd">` element and append them to it (and remove the `id` from the input)

Comment: @EhsanAbd nothing error at firebug console

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just replace `<input id="idd" type="file" multiple="true" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">` with `<ul id="idd"></ul>` but same nothing listdown

Comment: You also need `return Json(salesFiles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` or add the `method: 'Post"` ajax option (the default is `Get`) And there is no need for the extra overhead of `.ToList()`

Comment: But it appears you trying to return a collection of `FileInfo`. Instead you should be returning a collection of `string` containing the property you want to display in the view (but what is `Url` anyway - its not a property of `FileInfo`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nope its(`Url`) not a property of `FileInfo` , just want to list down files as links  , is this possible to do ?

Comment: But you have `val.Url` in your script (what your returning does not have a property `Url`). Are you just wanting to list the names of all the files?

Comment: my plan is list down files as clickable links , but If its impossible to do , I wish to  just list the names of all the files

Comment: Yes its possible, but how will you be generating the links? Do you have a controller method that returns a `FileResult` so you can download them?

Comment: Nope I don't have controller method to generate the links , Actually I don't want to complicate this , for now just want to list down the files, what should I do now ,

Comment: Need a break for a while. I'll add an answer in an hour or so showing how to list the file names, and then we ca expand it later to include links for downloading the actual files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a number of errors

1. The element with `id="idd"` is an `<input>` and you cannot append
   `<li>` elements to an `<input>` (only a `<ul>` element)
2. Your ajax call is making a GET call, but your have not included
   `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` so nothing will be returned
3. Your attempting returning `List<FileInfo>` but accessing the `Url`
   property which dos not exist.
4. Even if you were to access the (say) `FullName` property, creating
   `<a href="http://C:/filePath.someFileName.xls` would not navigate to
   the file on the server

Since it appears you only want the name of the file, then your code should be

Html

```
<ul id="filelist"></ul>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("filesinfolder", "Home")', // don't hardcode
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
      $('#filelist').append($('<li></li>').text(item));
    });
  },
   error: function () {

  }
   });
 });
```

Note the `contentType` option is not required

Controller

```
public JsonResult filesinfolder()
{
    string salesFTPPath = "C:/filePath";
    DirectoryInfo salesFTPDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(salesFTPPath);
    IEnumerable<string> files = salesFTPDirectory.GetFiles()
      .Where(f => f.Extension == ".xls" || f.Extension == ".xml" || f.Extension == ".jps" || f.Extension == ".jpg" || f.Extension == ".jpeg" || f.Extension == ".png")
      .OrderBy(f => f.Name)
      .Select(f => f.FullName);
    return Json(files, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: its not list down file name just list down as `item`

Comment: now its working properly , but its showing files with full path like this `C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\rootProject\project_name\project_name\Content\Essential_Folder\marketing_materials_EN\01\4394.jpg` how to avoid full path , just the name

Comment: Change `.Select(f => f.FullName);` to `.Select(f => f.Name);`. But you have nother issue as well. It might be returning files when running in local host but as soon as your publish this to a server, its going to fail. But I'm not really sure what your wanting to do so not sure of the best way to handle this

Comment: do I have solution for both localhost and server ?

Comment: IF I explain briefly I just want to show files in specific folder in my edit view , since Its complicate to show with clickble links I just moved to just show the filenames , Am I clear ?

Comment: You will need to create a folder in your app (say) MyFiles and then use `Server.MapPath()`. I'll find a few links for you a bit later to look at (including how to download the files)

Comment: For setting the path to the folder use `string salesFTPPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/MyFiles");` assuming you have a folder named `MyFiles` in the `App_Data` folder. For downloading files, start with the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-asp-net-mvc) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GET request then you need to explicitly allow get requests on JSON results.

```
  public JsonResult filesinfolder()
    {
        DirectoryInfo salesFTPDirectory = null;
        FileInfo[] files = null;

        string salesFTPPath = "C:/filePath";

        salesFTPDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(salesFTPPath);
        files = salesFTPDirectory.GetFiles();

        files = files.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToArray();

        var salesFiles = files.Where(f => f.Extension == ".xls" || f.Extension == ".xml" || f.Extension == ".jps" || f.Extension == ".jpg" || f.Extension == ".jpeg" || f.Extension == ".png");

        return Json(salesFiles.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Also, consider returning just the data you need to your view. The `FileInfo` object is complex and might not be easily serialized.

Hope this helps