# Download File using MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I cannot find a reference to downloading a file using MVC Core.

We have a single exe file for members to download from our website. In the past we have put

`<a href=(file path)> Download < /a>` for our users to click. I would like to do something equivalent in MVC Core along the lines of

```
<a href=@ViewData["DownloadLink"]> Download < /a>
```

with DownloadLink populated with the file path.

```cs
public class DownloadController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["DownloadLink"] = ($"~/Downloads/{V9.Version}.exe");
        return View();
    }
}
```

`

The link `<a href=@ViewData["DownloadLink"]> Download < /a>` gets the correct path, but when clicked only renders the path in the address bar. Is there a simple way to set a download link?

Comment: Your action should return a content result, not a view. Look into the Controller.File method.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult/3605510#3605510) answer posted by @Tieson T to come up with this solution

```
    public FileResult Download()
    {
        var fileName = $"{V9.Version}.exe";
        var filepath = $"Downloads/{fileName}";
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
        return File(fileBytes, "application/x-msdownload", fileName);
    }
```

The view is now

```
<a asp-action="Download" asp->
Download
```

@Ageonix was also correct about not requiring the ~ to get to wwwroot

Comment: `return File`, this File is a static class, how can I use this in .Net Core 2.0?

Comment: File is a static method in "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase" that returns "FileContentResult".It is similar to "Ok()" or "NotFound()". FileContentResult is StatusResult just like  OkResult.

Comment: If you are using .net core, you probably wanna use wwwroot in the filepath, eg: var filePath = $"wwwroot/downloads/{fileName}";

Comment: Thanks for this straight forward answer. Works for me 100%

Answer (score 1):

I'm not somewhere where I can try it, but would something like this do the trick?

```
<a href="<%= Url.Content('~/Downloads/{ V9.Version}.exe') %>"> Download </a>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ageonix for the suggestion but VS2015 is complaining href is missing a closing angle bracket. I assume that is to do the with double-quotes within double-quotes but I can't get it right.

Comment: Oops.  Try using a single tick on those inner quotes instead.

Comment: I'm not sure how your site structure is, but if you're getting a 400 are you sure you need the tilde (~) on there?  In other words, have you double-checked to see if you're getting to the right place?

Comment: None of the variations on @Ageonix. answer seems to parse the path correctly. My first attempt gets the correct path, but doesn't download. Is this an MVC thing ... the path has to point to a controller action and cannot point to a file to download?