# ASP.net MVC Database backup

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to backup my database and I want to get that file as a download file. Simply when you get some kind of file from any website, they are just downloaded. I want to backup my database without setting a directory to that.

```
sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database test to disk='" + backupDIR + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + ".Bak'", con);
```

In this coding it sets a backup directory. I want to get that file as a downloaded file via browser.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  public FileResult Download()
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\folder\myfile.ext");
        string fileName = "myfile.ext";
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult)

Comment: Actually i doesnt work well. i dont know why is that. i have created .bak file. i used your code aswell. but its nothing.

Comment: Hi, did you replace the @"c:\folder\myfile.ext" for the current location of the file? I also recommend you using a relative path.

How are you calling the method from the view? 

I strongly recommend you to read this, http://rachelappel.com/upload-and-download-files-using-asp-net-mvc/ . It will clarify it.

Comment: Hi, Please check this code. i add this code. but its not working. i dont know why is that??i put that code as a answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  public ActionResult Backup()
    {
        BackupDB db = new BackupDB();

        if (db.BackupDatabase())
        {
            ViewData["Success"] = "Backup is completed Successfully";
            Download("09062016_200840.Bak");
            return View("AdminIndex");
        }

        ViewData["Exception"] = "Backup Failed";
        return View("AdminIndex");

    }
    public FileResult Download(string ImageName)
    {
        return File("‪C:\\Backups" + ImageName,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    }
```

Comment: First of all, it doesn't have a slash.
It is searching the file in C:\\Backups09062016_200840.Bak i think you are  looking it in C:\\Backups\\09062016_200840.Bak
Please, read this http://rachelappel.com/upload-and-download-files-using-asp-net-mvc/ it will help you a lot