# MVC: File does not get downloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to download an excel file but nothing happens.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            grid.RenderControl(htw);
            HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Daily_Report_" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ".xls");
            this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            byte[] temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htw.InnerWriter.ToString().Replace("<div>", "").Replace("</div>", ""));
            grid.Dispose();
            htw.Dispose();
            return File(temp, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Similar code is working fine in another page. (I am new to mvc so please bear with me).

I also tried these:

```
 return File("test.xls", System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Path.GetFileName("test.xls"));



return File(temp, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "Test.xls");
            //return File(temp, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

**CSHTML**

```
   //window.location.href = "/MeterLog/Export";  // this works but i want the below approach to work: 

            var fltrFromDate = $("#FromDate").val();
            var fltrToDate = $("#ToDate").val();
            var type = $('input:radio[name=Status]:checked').val()
            box = new ajaxLoader(this, { classOveride: 'blue-loader', bgColor: '#000' });
            var dataJSON = { "fltrFromDate": fltrFromDate, "fltrToDate": fltrToDate, "onoff": type };
            var str = "";
            box = new ajaxLoader(this, { classOveride: 'blue-loader', bgColor: '#000' });
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Export", "MeterLog")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: { "fltrFromDate": fltrFromDate, "fltrToDate": fltrToDate, "onoff": type }
            })
```

**NOTE:** I just found out that if i hardcode the parameters in the controller and replace the ajax call with `window.location.href = "/MeterLog/Export";` then it works! Why?

Comment: Off topic, but when constructing the filename why not just use `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_hhmm");`

Comment: duly noted. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file of any type in Asp.Net MVC using FileResult?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult)

Comment: @MANISH I have tried those, Its still not working.

Comment: If you are hosting your application on IIS, make sure that you enable the option to send files.

Comment: @DominikB I am working on local host  and similar code is working on other page.

Comment: @DominikB  I just found out that if i hardcode the parameters in the controller and replace the ajax call with `window.location.href = "/MeterLog/Export";` then it works. But why? I need to pass object to the controller

Comment: @MANISH please see my update

Comment: You cannot use ajax to download a file. Refer [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)