# ASP MVC Web App files & folders names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption, filesystems

I'm developing a web app that is going to have many files for news, photo galleries, users, products...also PDF documents associated to database records.

I'm going to store the images & docs in folders in the server and I'm wondering if it is a good practice or it is not necessary to encrypt those files & folders.

So, for example, for a photo gallery , let's say `GalleryId = 233`, I'm going to create the folder `"~/Files/Galleries/233/"` and store all the photos inside.
Also for a certain document, let's say `"DocId = 22"`, I'd need the root `"~/Files/Docs/22.pdf"`...

Would it be necessary to encrypt those numbers so the users don't see the real Ids and see something like `"aR2wdwewei"`...?

Waste os time? Better to encrypt? Pros and cons?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no difference between `int` ID or `hash` Id except one.

If someone wants to download all your server files with `int` name files it will be much more easier for him to get all data.

So if you want to protect yourself from this kind of "bruteforce download" - use `GUID`.

It's even better to create controller method that will return you any file you want. That way you will have one place where you can write access logs and restrict access if you need.

Comment: Well, my entities have int, not guid, but what I do is encrypt the Id with an algorithm to a base 64 name. ALso, could you explain me the controller method thing?

Comment: @JohnMathison just create 1 method to with you pass your hash and it will return file to you.

Comment: could you please put a link or something with an example...(sorry). Thanks.

Comment: @JohnMathison check what we got [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult)

Comment: Thanks @teo, but those files are not for download only, I'm also talking about the file we publish in the site, such as product files...nobody downloads those images, are just there so people can see the files. Do I need todo the same woith those files?

Comment: Yeap, you do. There is no difference