# HttpResponseMessage Returning Json Object in browser instead of file download - WEBAPI .net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

The below code is returning JSON object instead of downloading the PDF file:

```
var dataStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\data\test12.pdf"));
                dataStream.Position = 0;
                HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                responseMsg.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
                responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
                responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = file.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
                result = responseMsg;
```

output:

> **{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Disposition","value":["inline; filename=4159a9f5-0102-46c3-a39f-7449c00e39e5.pdf"]},{"key":"Content-Type","value":["application/pdf"]},{"key":"Content-Length","value":["7874"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}**

Comment: Your code does not return anything currently - it is missing a return statement. Could you add a bit more context?

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage get(long id){
var dataStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\data\test12.pdf"));

..........
return result;


}

Comment: Please add everything relevant to your question. Use the edit button.

Comment: Hi, any update here?

Answer (score 1):

> The below code is returning JSON object instead of downloading the pdf
> file.

This is the expected result when you call this api. In your current code the framework is treating `HttpResponseMessage` as a model.

The correct way to download a file after calling the api should be:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var dataStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\data\test12.pdf"));
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
    return File(dataStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

If you want to use `HttpResponseMessage`, you need call the api by ajax.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41115583/11398810