# Gives a HTTP404 Error (Azure Storage/Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, filestream

i am working on a website where you could upload a image onto azure storage as a blob and also to download the blob, however when i download the image it gives me a "this file format cannot be opened" when opening the pic. i was wondering where could i display the fileStream?

heres my javascript:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">

@Html.ActionLink("Upload to Azure Blob", "UploadBlob", new { Controller = "blob" }, new { @class = "btn btn-link" })

<div class=" table table-striped table-responsive">

    <table id=" tablex">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Container</th>
                <th>Actual FileName</th>
                <th> Uri </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @if(Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {

            <tr id="row_@item.PrimaryUri">
                <td>@item.BlockContainerName</td>
                <td>@item.ActualFileName</td>

                <td>
                    <a herf=@item.PrimaryUri>@item.PrimaryUri </a>
                </td>
                @*<td>@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "DeletedBlob", new { controller = "blob", file = @item.FileNameWithoutExt, extension = @item.FileNameWithoutExt })</td> *@

                <td><a href='@Url.Action("Download", "DownloadBlob", new { file = @item.FileNameWithoutExt, extension = @item.FileNameWithoutExt })'>Download</a></td>

                <td>
                    <input type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-link" id="btndel" value="Remove" data-id="@item.ActualFileName" />
                </td>

            </tr>

                }

            }

        </tbody>



    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript method ive written in order to download the blob however i've been trying to find out where the problem

In my controller class i have:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadBlob(string file, string extension)
{
    string downloadPath = await repo.DownloadBlobAsync(file, extension);
    return Json(downloadPath);
}
```

and in my storage class:

```
public async Task<string> DownloadBlobAsync (string file, string fileExtension)
{
    _cloudBlobContainerx = _cloudBlobClientx.GetContainerReference(containerNamex);
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = _cloudBlobContainerx.GetBlockBlobReference(file + "." + fileExtension);

    var path = downloadPath + file + "." + fileExtension;
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path))
    {
        //fileStream.Position = 1;
        //fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);

        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why return json result for file download? You should return file result.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Could you show me a example please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc-file-upload-and-download/

Answer (score 0):

You are using your file name as your extension in your Action;

`extension = @item.FileNameWithoutExt`

It could explain why get the 404, as the blob probably don't exist with this extension.

Comment: However even if i replace is with .ActualFileName or FileExtension i get same result

Answer (score 0):

We need to use the @Url.Action as following:`@Url.Action("actionName","controlName",routeValues)`.

> Gives a HTTP404 Error (Azure Storage/Visual Studio)

It indicates that can't route that path. So you could add the controller named  `DownloadBlob` and add the method **Download**. We need to make sure that it has the same paramter name are in the routeValues.

```
public void Download(string file, string extension)
{
    var container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
    container.CreateIfNotExists();
    var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file + "." + fileExtension);
    blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
    var contentType = blockBlob.Properties.ContentType;   
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
    var response = HttpContext.Response;
    response.ContentType = contentType;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + file + "." + fileExtension);
    response.AddHeader("Content-Length", blockBlob.Properties.Length.ToString());
    response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
}
```

The following is the test result on my side.

[image]

Comment: I ran the exact same thing however "blockBlob.FetchAttributes();" line has returned a "The remote server returned an error: (404) not found"

Comment: Any idea why? @TomSun

Comment: You could debug and check the blob name.

Comment: It means that couldn't found the blob. The extension name shoud be no dot.