# How to let user download data to a file

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to let user download data I am displaying elsewhere in the website as reports.

I am using Asp.net core 2.1 rc1 MVC app.

My cunning plan was to create a special view which would render data as a tab delimited text and use response headers to make browser download it instead of displaying HTML. This almost works perfectly.

My "HttpGet" code in the controller looks like this:

```
 Response.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=export.tsv");
 return View(MyModel);
```

My razor view looks like this:

```
@Model IEnumerable<MyModel>
@{
     Layout = null;
     String LineBreak = Environment.NewLine;
     String Tab = "\t";
}

Header1 Header2 ...

    @if (Model.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (MyModel myModel in Model)
        {
            @myModel.Field1@Html.Raw(@Tab)@myModel.Field2 ... @Html.Raw(@LineBreak)
        }
    }
```

This works splendidly except that this ugly error message appears as a first line in the file:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyApp.Models.MyModel] IEnumerable<MyModel>
```

The rest of the file is exactly what I need.

Does anyone know how to remove this message? Or if there is something wrong with my general approach...

Full project available here: https://github.com/under3415/ExportError/ (just click on download link and examine the file)

Comment: That's not an error message. You are somewhere rendering that, perhaps some `@Html.Raw(model)` or something like that.

Comment: This is probably not an error message, but the result of a call to `ToString()` on some object.

Comment: The thing is both ToString and Html.Raw work just fine. Everything is displayed perfectly.

Comment: Well... post the entire file and we might be able to help

Comment: OK, I'll put something on GitHub

Comment: hi, I've added the project to github: https://github.com/under3415/ExportError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written `@Model`, while the correct syntax is `@model` (lowercase - it's case-sensitive).

A first-line `@model` directive specifies the model type. `@Model` dereferences the actual model instance. What you're seeing is its `ToString` representation.

Comment: Thanks so much, totally missed that! Still not sure why was everything else working!?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're returning view with the model **return View(MyModel);**, you should be using **FileResult**

Here are the complete instructions on it
[Download file of any type in Asp.Net MVC using FileResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I don't really want to return a file. All my formatting is done in the view. I can easily return an Excel file or a tab delimited text file. I want to return a view and have browser save it as a file. If I was going to use a file instead of file, I guess I would have to create the file in memory and stream it to a file. This is so much easier done in a view.