# How To Download A file From FileResult and anchor tag in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, fileresult

**THIS IS MY FILE UPLOAD AND DOWNLOAD CODE**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Rent Rent , FileUpload upload, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (Rent.Id == 0)
            _Context.Rent.Add(Rent);

        else
        {
            var rentInDb = _Context.Rent.Single(c => c.Id == Rent.Id);

            rentInDb.tenantId = Rent.tenantId;
            rentInDb.unitId = Rent.unitId;
            rentInDb.startDate = Rent.startDate;
            rentInDb.endDate = Rent.endDate;
            rentInDb.Amount = Rent.Amount;
            rentInDb.leaseStatus = Rent.leaseStatus;


        }

            _Context.SaveChanges();

        var rent = _Context.Rent.Single(r => r.Id == Rent.Id);

        var up = Request.Files["file"];
        if (up.ContentLength > 0) {



            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), guid + fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            string fl = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\"));
            string[] split = fl.Split('\\');
            string newpath = split[1];
            string imagepath = "~/uploads/" + newpath;
            upload.length = imagepath;
            upload.Rent = rent;
            _Context.FileUpload.Add(upload);
            _Context.SaveChanges();

        }
        return RedirectToAction("leaseStatus", "Home");
    }


 public ActionResult Downloads(int id)
    {
        var fl = _Context.FileUpload.Where(f => f.rentId == id);
        var up = Request.Files["file"];




        return View(fl );
    }

public FileResult Download(string ImageName)
  {
          var FileVirtualPath = "~/uploads/" + ImageName;

        return File(FileVirtualPath, "application/force-download", Path.GetFileName(FileVirtualPath));


}
```

THIS IS MY VIEW !!

```html
@model IEnumerable<mallform.Models.FileUpload>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Downloads";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Downloads</h2>


@foreach (var file in Model)
{
   

    

    <a href=@file.length target="_blank">Download</a>

}
```

THIS SHOWS STANDARD 404.0 AND SOMETIME hidden element error :( Please help. In my code it includes the upload a file code,
then there Is a download action which leads me to download view and In download view, I have a link to download the file by file result. But It always shows me an error. Please tell me if there is an issue with the path or what is going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file of any type in Asp.Net MVC using FileResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult)

Comment: Your ActionMethod `Download(string ImageName)` is taking `imageName` as param and in `<a href=@file.length` you are not specify the name of the actionmethod and ImageName param. That's why it is showing 404, because the anchor tag is not hitting that actionmethod.

Comment: Thanks man but now it says : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\mall-90f203a01a995e8b804a90b7e188646c7cc895c3\mallform\uploads\~\uploads\a5ff7121-2c1c-451e-9c8c-e6d69a5ccf751st image.jpg'.

Comment: Use `var FileVirtualPath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + ImageName);`

Comment: same could not find path error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error Code 404 means the url is not found by your anchor tag. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

You need to pass **ImageName** parameter from your anchor tag to the controller. You can do something like this:

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<mallform.Models.FileUpload>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Downloads";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Downloads</h2>


@foreach (var file in Model)
{

    @Html.ActionLink(
          "Download File",              // Anchor Text
          "Download",                   // Action Name 
          "Controller Name",            // Controller Name
           new {                 
                 ImageName= "Pass the value of imagename parameter"
               },
           null         // Html Attributes
          )
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public FileResult Download(string ImageName)
      {
     //var FileVirtualPath = "~/uploads/" + ImageName; 

    //If using Physical Path  
    //var FileVirtualPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/uploads/" + ImageName); 

    //If using Virtual Path
     var FileVirtualPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + ImageName);   

     return File(FileVirtualPath, "application/force-download", Path.GetFileName(FileVirtualPath));

    }
```

Comment: thanks man , it has recognized the action name but now it says  : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\mall-90f203a01a995e8b804a90b7e188646c7cc895c3\mallform\uploads\~\uploads\a5ff7121-2c1c-451e-9c8c-e6d69a5ccf751st image.jpg'.

Comment: Because the image url is not correct. Is it the actual path to the image  'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\mall-90f203a01a995e8b804a90b7e188646c7cc895c3\mallform\uploads\~\uploads\a5ff7121-2c1c-451e-9c8c-e6d69a5ccf751st image.jpg'

Comment: 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\mall-90f203a01a995e8b804a90b7e188646c7cc895c3\mallform\uploads\a5ff7121-2c1c-451e-9c8c-e6d69a5ccf751st image.jpg'vvv  actual path should be this but it shows uploads twice man what to do ?

Comment: @VikramSharma - Updated the answer. Check now

Comment: I will mark you as answer man , thank you all I did is removed the whole path in my file result method   var FileVirtualPath = "~/uploads/" + ImageName; as :   var FileVirtualPath = "" + ImageName; and the file got downloaded

Comment: Great. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

File Result Action should be like this.

```
public FileResult Download(string ImageName)
{

    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(@"~/uploads/"+ImageName));
   string fileName = "myfile."+Path.GetExtension(Server.MapPath(@"~/uploads/"+ImageName));
return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);


}
```

Comment: after this I  Changed my download link to : foreach (var file in Model)




    Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { ImageName = file.length }) 
}
 and it says DirectoryNotFound Exception

Comment: make sure Uploads file is present inside project

Comment: Yes it is inside my project only .