# How to Download Edited PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have pdf with bytes  i am reading that pdf with

```
byte[] pdfContent =[];

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfContent); 

using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputStream))
    {
        AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
        pdfFormFields .SetField("txtForename", "Test"));
        pdfStamper.Close();
        array = outputStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

How to download this edit pdf with memorystream

Comment: what do you mean by downloading? what kind of application are we dealing with? is it console application? web application? who is going to download the file? are the clients request file via browser?

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605510/809357

Comment: i was edit my pdf i want to download edited pdf

Comment: Do you want to save to disk? or download via url?

Comment: How to get edit pdf here

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is seems wrong. You have empty PdfContent and you are  you are trying to open pdf with empty content I guess. Furthermore, you dont need MemoryStream because your intention will be to write your file to disk (filestream would be your best option for this)

this example can help you on editing your pdf.

```
private void fillPDFForm()
{
    string formFile = Server.MapPath(P_InputStream);
    string newFile = Server.MapPath(P_OutputStream);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formFile);
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

        // set form fields
        fields.SetField("name", "John Doe");
        fields.SetField("address", "xxxxx, yyyy");
        fields.SetField("postal_code", "12345");
        fields.SetField("email", "johndoe@xxx.com");

        // flatten form fields and close document
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        stamper.Close();
    }
}
```

further reference: https://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/

Comment: Here i am not able to get the edited pdf , in that path pdf was empty not able to see what i edited in pdf

Comment: without placing that document in path can we download like if we download anything from internet we can see that in browser history download path are default path