# How can I get file from filepath in ASP.NET and return the file to the client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am very new in ASP.NET. I want help about how to get file from specific location and send to the client through action controller.

Comment: Controllers can return `FileResult`, if you which the client to download a file, then check returning `FileResult` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult)

Answer (score 0):

To send any file to the client from the server I can use..............

```
        var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(inkFormulation.DocumentPath);
        var ext = ImageFormat.Jpeg;// the file extension you want to use 
        return base.File(fileBytes, $"image/{ext}", $"SampleImage.{ext}");
```

This is for image file. You can send any file with specific file extension.