# Download Files from View in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is my View Code and I am using a ViewBag to get the files from controller

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  @foreach (var File in ViewBag.ProjectsFiles)
  {
  <li>
  <span class="text-secondary"> @File.FilesName <span class="btn-link text-secondary"><a  href="http://localhost:44360/Test/Index/DownloadFile?file=@File.FilesName" target="_blank" class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></a></span></span>
  </li>
  }
  </ul>
```

and this is my controller method to download the files on click in link

```
public void DownloadFile(String file)
        {
            try
            {
                String filename = file;
                String filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + filename);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                Response.Flush();

                Response.TransmitFile(filepath);
                Response.End();
                // HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                ViewBag.Message = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = ex.Message.ToString();
            }

        }
```

But the probleme when I click the file's not downloading. Any hints?

Comment: did you debug it and set a breakpoint in the controller?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander not yet

Comment: **Warning:** You are setting yourself up for a [path traversal exploit](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal). Pass in `../../WebApplication1.sln` to the DownloadFile function and if the file exists it will happily return it. Validate your user input for these kind of characters.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code below, this will return the file when controller is called. You can find related information on this link [Download file of any type in Asp.Net MVC using FileResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult)

```
        public FileResult Download(String file)
    {
        String filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + file);
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, file);
    }
```